# Is it possible for adjacent Svelte stores to update each other?

Tags: javascript, frontend, state, svelte

I'm coming from React/Redux-land and am slowly getting acquainted to Svelte design patterns using stores.

Currently I'm curious to figure out if this is an acceptable pattern or if not, what is a better way to pursue this kind of communication. The basic premise is I want to be able to update multiple custom stores (which are using writable) from an adjacent store.

In the example below I have "*loading.js*" and "*error.js*" stores which would be used globally, commented out in the "*session.js*" store. I'd like to update these based on the result of an API request to create a session, in order to keep most of my heavy lifting out side of components.

My current thinking is that I'd pass each store needed through the "*createSessionStore*" function, but it feels a little clunky as it would highly depend on the declaration order of each store within "*store.js*"

The long term intention for wishing to do it this way is so I can add any kind of communication layer (such as web sockets) in to the mix and update the global loading or error store from any layer.

Thanks for the help.

**Component.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { error, loading, session } from "./store";

  onMount(() => {
     session.fetchSession();
  }); 
</script>

{#if $loading}
  <div>Loading...</div>
{/if}

{#if $error}
  <div>Something went wrong: {$error}</div>
{/if}
```

**store.js**

```js
import { createErrorStore } from "./error";
import { createLoadingStore } from "./loading";
import { createSessionStore } from "./session";

export const error = createErrorStore();
export const loading = createLoadingStore();
export const session = createSessionStore();
```

**session.js**

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const INITIAL_STORE = {
    token: null
};

export const createSessionStore = (initialStore = INITIAL_STORE) => {

    const { subscribe, set } = writable(initialStore);

    const fetchSession = async () => {
        // loading.set(true);

        try {
            const response = await fetch("MY_API_ENDPOINT/auth/token", {
                method: "POST",
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const err = new Error("Network response was not ok.");
                // error.set(err);
                // loading.set(false);
                return;
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            set(data.token);
            // loading.set(false);
        } catch (err) {
            // error.set(err);
            // loading.set(false);
        }
    };

    const reset = () => {
        set(initialStore);
    };

    return {
        subscribe,
        fetchSession,
        reset
    };
};
```

**error.js**

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const INITIAL_STORE = false;

export const createErrorStore = (initialStore = INITIAL_STORE) => {

    const { subscribe, set } = writable(initialStore);

    const reset = () => {
        set(initialStore);
    };

    return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        reset
    };
};
```

**loading.js**

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const INITIAL_STORE = false;

export const createLoadingStore = (initialStore = INITIAL_STORE) => {

    const { subscribe, set } = writable(initialStore);

    const reset = () => {
        set(initialStore);
    };

    return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        reset
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea.

The problem here is that during the creation of the stores, not all of them exists yet. The only solution that I see for this is to add the references after creating them.

Here's my idea:

In the `session.js`:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const INITIAL_STORE = {
    token: null
};

export const createSessionStore = (initialStore = INITIAL_STORE) => {

    const { subscribe, set } = writable(initialStore);

    const fetchSession = async () => {
        // loading.set(true);

        try {
            otherStores.loading && otherStores.loading.set(true);
            const response = await fetch("MY_API_ENDPOINT/auth/token", {
                method: "POST",
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const err = new Error("Network response was not ok.");

                otherStores.error && otherStores.error.set(err);
                otherStores.loading && otherStores.loading.set(false);
                return;
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            set(data.token);
        } catch (err) {
          otherStores.error && otherStores.error.set(err);
          otherStores.loading && otherStores.loading.set(false);
        }
    };

    const reset = () => {
        set(initialStore);
    };

    let otherStores = {}
    const setOtherStores = (stores) => {
        otherStores=stores
    };


    return {
        subscribe,
        fetchSession,
        reset,
        setOtherStores
    };
};
```

In the `store.js`:

```
import { createErrorStore } from "./error";
import { createLoadingStore } from "./loading";
import { createSessionStore } from "./session";

export const error = createErrorStore();
export const loading = createLoadingStore();
export const session = createSessionStore();

session.setOtherStores({error,loading})
```

You can use the same pattern for any of the other stores (if needed), and after creation pass them the references to the other stores.